# Raising attention for primary button in competition to the header

Tags: buttons, color, hierarchy, header

I am searching for some help with our primary color. We are using blue as the primary color and placed it into the header to support the brand's identity.

On the other hand, blue is also our primary button color. The placing of our CTAs was easy, till today.

With our list view, I tend to place it directly under the header. The problem: the focus gets lost because the attention for the button is less effective through the immense use by the header.

Do you know how to replace the button or change the style to make it more attractive?

Placing it to the bottom right should be the last solution because we reserved the corner bottom right for a chat/support button.

Thank you together :)

[image: Example of the primary color problem]

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use a single color? Use a color palette formed by a primary and a secondary/ accent color.

Answer (score 2):

Use a tool like Adobe Kuler:

https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/

To find tertiary and complimentary colours for your design. That way you don't have to use your header blue for your primary & secondary CTA etc.

Answer (score 0):

A new formal typology can be established for the set of buttons near the header, like using the same blue color in an outlined button.

[image]